# Finding orthonormal basis. Is there error on textbook?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

The problem is finding orthonormal basis for W=span{u1=x,u2=x^2}

And as lots of people think, it is not very difficult problem

My answer is

${ \sqrt{3}x,\sqrt{80}(x^2-\frac{3}{4}x) }$

But, textbook says

$ \sqrt{3}x,\sqrt{30}(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x)$

I checked another edition of the textbook but it was same.

I use elementary linear algebra by koleman

Is there any error I have made? Because of this problem I can’t believe my answer for similar problems.[image]

Comment: Please, if you really need to include an image, could you ensure that it is the right way up.

Comment: Orthonormal with respect to which inner product?

Comment: I changed the image!

Comment: Which inner product? As I know inner product of polynomials are integral of them. Isn’t it?

Comment: For any interval $I$ and any positive function $w$ on $I$, $$\left<f,g\right>=\int_I f(x)g(x)w(x)\,dx$$ defines an inner product. The choice of interval $I$ and weight function $w$ does affect what the inner product is.

Comment: Off topic:  on Amazon, the number of negative reviews that this book has received is staggering.

Comment: Oh... my professor taught me that interval is always 0 to 1 and weighted function is 1.

Comment: He also said that the book has received lots of negative review but he believes that the book is the best one.

Comment: Then, my answer is right?

Comment: In answer to your question: you are right. Whoever did the solutions probably forgot that the second term needed to be multiplied by $x$ too when making sure they are orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I want to accept your answer but can I do accept for comment too? Not only for upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book's answer isn't orthogonal:   $(x,x^2-\frac12x)=\int_0^1x(x^2-\frac12x)\operatorname dx=[x^4/4-x^3/6]_0^1\neq0$.

Yours, on the other hand,  appears to be correct.